# Need to call onclick event when component is running mode

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey

I have created a component using TPanel in Firemonkey. My idea is to click my component in run time and implement some functionality. So when I drag my component on the form and run application then I clicked on my component that time my function will work.

Here I created a Component, source code are as follows:

```
unit Layout1;

interface

uses
  FMX.controls, System.Classes,FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Types,System.UITypes, System.SysUtils,FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TTestPnl = class(TPanel)  // inherit panel
  private
  protected
  public
     Pnl  : TPanel;
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    procedure Click; override;
  published

end;

procedure Register;

implementation


// Creation component at run time with assigning onclick event
constructor TTestPnl .Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;
    Pnl  := TPanel.Create(Self);
    with Pnl do
    begin
      Height := 145.000000000000000000;
      Position.X := 408.000000000000000000;
      Position.Y := 40.000000000000000000;
      Width := 201.000000000000000000;
      TabOrder := 0;
      OnClick  := click;
end;

// Implementing Onclick functionality for runtime
procedure TTestPnl .Click;
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('Click Event Call');
end;


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('TestPnl', [TTestPnl]);
end;

end.
```

In my code when I drag component that time only click event call. But I need after drag component run application that time I click my component that time my procedure will call.

Comment: Do you really want that panel inside a panel?

Comment: no it just example, I want to call onclick event when component is running mode.

Comment: Surely Click already fires OnClick. Why don't you use a plain TPanel and use its existing OnClick?

Comment: OK, But inside Component code want to implement some functionality. So When I drag component on form at run time when i click on the component that function should be call.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain clearly what you are trying to do. Hard to see how OnClick could be appropriate.

Comment: I am trying to select, resize and move component at run time. So I know how to select component at  runtime also move. But where I need to put source code at the time of creation of component.

Comment: Why don't you ask that question? How can I enable my panel to be dragged and resized by the user at runtime?

Comment: I am just wondering why you have a derived panel component with an additional panel `Pnl` inside, that you did not show, but where you assigned to `OnClick` event. That is useless at all.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing use a TSelection.

To differentiate between clicking and dragging you'll need to monitor the OnMouseDown/OnMouseUp events (or override the methods in a component).

In MouseDown note the co-ordinates and set MouseCapture. Then monitor MouseMove events to mov your component. Set a flag if the mouse has moved more than n pixels from the start point (n will depend on how sensitive you want things).

In MouseUp if the flag has been set, move the component, otherwise return it to the start position and fire the OnClick event.